Finding the minimum distance between pairs of conjoined spheres
I have been working on geometry problems involving spheres in space, and I came across a fact that seems intuitively obvious but has been cumbersome to prove.
Suppose you have a two unit length line segment $\overline{ab}$ and $\overline{cd}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with endpoints $a$, $b$, and $c$, $d$, respectively. Furthermore, suppose that there are spheres of radius $1/2$ centered at $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, denoted by $B(a)$, $B(b)$, etc. If none of the spheres intersect (i.e. $B(a)\cap B(c)=B(a)\cap B(d)=B(b)\cap B(c)=B(b)\cap B(d)=\emptyset$), what is the minimum distance between $\overline{ab}$ and $\overline{cd}$?
After serious consideration, I strongly conjecture that the answer is $1/\sqrt{2}$ and that this distance is achieved by the midpoints of $\overline{ab}$ and $\overline{cd}$ precisely when $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ form the vertices of a regular tetrahedron (pictured here), meaning all of the spheres are touching.
I tried proving this conjecture by translating the problem into an optimization problem, where the function $f$ gives the distance between two arbitrary points on the line segments. Explicitly, I tried to minimize the function $$f=\|(t_1a+(1-t_1)b)-(t_2c+(1-t_2)d)\|$$
subject to
$$\|a-b\|=\|c-d\|=1$$
$$\|a-c\|\geq 1$$
$$\|a-d\|\geq 1$$
$$\|b-c\|\geq 1$$
$$\|b-d\|\geq 1$$
but this is quite messy and seems to require heavier machinery than just Lagrange multipliers (e.g. KKT conditions).
My question is this: is there a simpler proof (perhaps using more geometry and less optimization) of my conjecture?
